# C++ event system - using heap or stack based events

Tags: c++, design-patterns, event-handling

I'm trying to design a simple event system that, "basically", looks like this:

- *the observer* entity keeps a list of all objects that need to be notified. It also stores a queue of fired events. Events are then processed by the object list, iteratint through this object list.
- *an object* keeps a list of observers it sends events to. Each particular object, that inherits from the base object, can fire its own specialised events (key, mouse, collision, etc.). The object also has a method `HandleEvent(..)` with different overloads for compile time type detection, instead of using `dynamic_casting`.

What would be better to choose, when firing events: creating them on the stack and passing them by reference, or allocating them dynamically on the heap and use dynamic_casting and let the observer deallocate them when they're processed by the objects that can handle them? (e.g. isn't dynamic allocation unnecessary when an event can be fired quite often; what about dynamic casting, isn't it avoidable?).

Also, this is not quite a thread-safe scenario..

Comment: Please clarify what you mean when you say, "this is not quite a thread-safe scenario"

Comment: I fear that declaring objects on the stack (e.g. the events in a function body) might be a bad idea in a multi-threaded scenario, since those objects are likely to get destroyed while they're processed by another thread.

Comment: Well, you're right.  However in the scenario you wrote about, in neither case did you use stack-based allocation.

Comment: Oh, sorry, you're right, I saw the double "create them on a heap" sentence being used in the same phrase.

Comment: Great, thanks, that makes it a little more clear.

Comment: You're reinventing the wheel. Unless it is your homework or you're REALLY interested in solving this particular problem, I'd suggest to use boost::signal or Qt 4. "REALLY interested" means you can't sleep without solving it.

Comment: Boost is too big of a dependency to enforce it in a project. I am trying to learn about performance, design patterns and best practices.. it's not about reinventing wheels, it's about understanding their building process.

Comment: @teodron: "Boost is too big" C++ is quite messy when it comes to compiler support for certain features (cstdint, shared_ptr, etc), so it might be easier to add boost as dependency instead of trying to do it all yourself. "best practices" PRetty much every practice has both benefits and disadvantage. "understanding their building process" both Qt 4 and boost are opensource, and Qt is well documented. So you can either read source or documentation. Might take less time than doing it yourself.

Comment: @SigTerm ok, those are learning sources then, I'll check them shortly. Nevertheless, I was hoping for an answer with some explanations (like the one already given here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need dynamic allocation? No. Typically, you want

```
void fireEvent()
{
    Event ev;
    for ( each observer )
       observer.trigger(ev);
}
```

And the observer's signature

```
void trigger(const Event& ev);
```

Note that "passing references to them" isn't true, pedantically speaking. It's actually "passing them by reference".

Comment: Remark noted; if this  were a threaded scenario, what would happen to the event the trigger functions tries to inject to various handlers? (assuming the triggering is performed on different threads?).

Comment: The main reason is that although stack managed objects are, usually, preferable in terms of allocation speed to heap managed ones, if one tries to use multiple threads, the references could get corrupted.

Comment: The trigger could try and pass around an object that used to exist on the stack, but was destroyed upon the exit of the `void fireEvent()` method.. or is this not the standard behaviour? (I may be very confused..)